# Permission error using multiprocessing in Python 3.5 with unknown origin

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I'm facing a strange bug. I have a parent process that spawns two child processes with infinite loops that provide different services. Each child shares a `multiprocessing.manager.list()` variable type with the parent process. All processes (parent and children) are fully encapsulated in `try except finally` blocks so I can catch and process various errors. I've even used the `except Exception` term as a final *catch all* term. In spite of all this, I am still getting the following error pop up regularly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 100, in spawn_main
    new_handle = steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 86, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

From the log file I produce, there's no sign of it coming from any of my processes (which is obvious given the traceback), and given what I see in the code this has no effect on the program. I'm under the impression that for the `multiprocessing.Manager` to function to work it needs to generate a separate process just for shuttling these variables around. The problem is that I really need to at least hide the error from the command prompt. A lot of information is being presented to the user there and stray errors popping up regularly is very distracting.

I can't show code unfortunately as I'm at work, and as its many thousands of lines at the moment I'm not sure of the exact source of the bug. I will continue trying to narrow things down and if I do manage to create a small example I'll edit the question with it.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

`Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: I've not had much luck on my end with this, so I've ended up putting a `try, except all` around everything inside of one of the `multiprocessor` functions (`spawn_main` in `spawn.py` to be specific). This erks me to the point that I'm not even going to entertain the idea of posting it as a solution. However, I can't spend too much more time on this, and this hack job seems to do the job.